# What is the purpose of Plant Room, GSM Room and MCC Room in hotels?

Tags: hotels

Can someone explain me what is the purpose of:

- Plant Room,
- GSM Room and
- MCC Room

found in certain hotels (at least in one)?

I have just found them while staying at Premier Inn next to airport in Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates.

Both rooms are located at the topmost floor (where, in case of this hotel, there are no guest rooms, just the pool and the gym), both all closed all the time and both have "Keep Closed" label on doors.

MCC Room and GSM Room seems to be of size of a typical guest room (or two) while Plant Room seems to have the size of 1/3rd of entire floor, taking area of whole corridor and fifteen guest rooms.

I've visited a number of hotels previously, in many countries, including other hotels in UAE, but found these three rooms only in this Premier Inn hotel.

Comment: I'd guess that the 'GSM Room' houses equipment which runs a cell-phone tower on top of the hotel.

Comment: How do you know the size?  Have you looked inside?  The labels could have a myriad of meanings, GSM could be guest services manager, MCC could be meetings, conventions, congresses.

Comment: "Plant room" is [sense 2 on this wiktonary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plant_room). A swimming pool isn't merely a big hole filled with water - there's a *lot* of associated machinery

Comment: You can find these rooms **in any large building**, it has no connection to it being a hotel specifically.  They are just equipment rooms.  It's really surprisingly you haven't noticed such signs before, because every single building has such areas, marked "equipment room, keep out", "electrical panels, keep out" etc.

Comment: MCC - Motor Control Center
GSM - Global System for Mobile communications

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly guessing here, but:

- "Plant" sometimes refers to the various equipment that's needed to keep the building running (air conditioning, ventilation, heating, water heaters, water pumps, backup generators, pumps for the pool, etc.)
- As user brhans mentioned in the comments, "GSM Room" probably houses equipment for cell phone towers on top of the hotel (GSM is a cellphone technology)
- Looking through the list of meanings for the "MCC" acronym, one that stands out is "Motor Control Center". Buildings sometimes have rooms on top that house the motors and related equipment for the building elevators, so this would be my guess, especially if this room is next to the elevator shafts.